# on mouse over show x on image

Tags: html, css, css-position

i want to show X mark on image , which is 24x24 size,

for that i take li element and in element

```
<li style="display: inline-block; background: #283038; border: 1px solid #161b1f; margin: 5px; height: 25px; padding: 2px; border-radius: 3px;">
            <ul>
                <li style="width: auto; float: left;">
                    <img class='tagImage'/>
                                        <span class='removeitem'>X</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

something like this :
[image]

my problem is in html i am not able to place X icon on correct place. as per screenshot

Comment: Assuming it isn't all inline, could you post up your CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS Positioning techniques along with `display`.

Here, am setting the first `img` i.e the close icon to `display: none;` and on `:hover` of `div` I set it to block, make sure you use `position: relative;` on the parent element else it will fly out in the wild.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6495D/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div img:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: none;
}

div:hover img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

---

You are using `span` so instead of equivalent selectors would be

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6495D/2/)

```
ul > li > ul > li {
    position: relative;
}
ul > li > ul > li > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: none;
}
ul > li > ul > li:hover > span {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

In the above selectors, it's having the same logic as above, the crucial part is to wrap the `position: absolute;` element inside a `position: relative;` container,
and also about `>` selector, it means direct child, so I've specifically selected the levels of `li` you are 
having

Just get rid of the `height: 25px;` as well... and avoid using *inline* style declarations...

Comment: This is good, but it would be even better if you used the example of a text `X` like in the original question.

Comment: @ANeves our colleague is asking for X icon, not X as text

Comment: @equisde the question has HTML text `X` and not an image/icon, and the help asked is to position it and not to replace it with an image. I thought that both solutions would be fine, but a simpler one would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

set the **parent** of you span to **relative** and the **span** to **absolute** this is all you have to know

```
li{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:20px;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    display:none; 
}

li:hover span{
    display:block;   
}
```

html

```
<li>
    <span>x</span>
</li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4rFKA/)

if you apply the rule on multiple elements it looks like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4rFKA/1/)