# How to move the cross over image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html

```
<div class="image_canvas">
     <span class="img-tag"><span class="delete-img-tag">&times;</span>
    <img  class="img-thumbnail udp-img">
</span>
```

my css

```
.img-tag{
    background-color: rgb(217, 224, 231);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.delete-img-tag {
    background-position: 0 -690px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 12px;
    margin-top: 0.1px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

i want the cross to appear on the right on top of image and the image should cover whole of the blue area.

[image]

**http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kqf/1/**

Comment: I answered yesterday over here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148034/on-mouse-over-show-x-on-image/22148114#22148114 its somewhat similar

Comment: Do you have jsFiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the parent span **position:relative** and child **position:absolute; top:0px;** it will set the child span at top-left corner..

```
<div class="image_canvas">
     <span class="img-tag">
        <span class="delete-img-tag">&times;</span>
         <img  class="img-thumbnail udp-img" src="" height="70" width="100" />
    </span>
</div>
```

your css would be --

```
.img-tag{
    background-color: rgb(217, 224, 231);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(179, 206, 225);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;

    position:relative;
}

.img-tag:hover .delete-img-tag
{
    z-index:500;
}
.img-tag:hover img
{
    background-color:blue;
}

.delete-img-tag {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    font-size:150%; 
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:-9999;
}
```

check the below http://www.jsfiddle.net/TX5Pn

Comment: this looks nice but how to move the cross to the right side.

Comment: the only thing is you need to add the **right:0px;** in **delete-img-tag** class that's it..

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kqf/3/

Just make sure to set the parent div to

```
position: relative;
```

and every child element you want to position within this element to

```
position: absolute;
```

Then use e.g.

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

to position it in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach will probably be to add a div instead of an img element and assign the image as a background-image via css. Then just put the X as a child element in that div and position it on the right side via `float:right;` or just `text-align:right;` on the parent.